# Creating a Sharepoint work environment on Windows 7

Tags: sharepoint

I want to learn sharepoint.Can I create a work environment for sharepoint in Windows7? Is there any other options to work with Sharepoint on our laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but maybe you shouldn't, anyway its up to you at the end so here are some guides with the steps to do it:

http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2014/08/21/guest-blog-by-jonas-nilsson-install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-8-1.aspx

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZZkgu0BiGk

I have done it with SP 2010 but never tried with SP 2013, I never required to do so, either because the clients had environments or because you can develop everything you need with SP Online by using Apps, the second one is the biggest reason.

In case you want to know the alternatives proposed by Microsoft here are them:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179924.aspx

The second one is the one I recomend because is for App development on SP Online.

Here is a previous discussion about this topic:

[installing-sharepoint-2013-windows-7](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41204/installing-sharepoint-2013-windows-7)

Comment: Thanks @mpsemi, what do you think is missing on the information I provided to be considered as right answer for your question? I'm wondering because you didnt selected it as the answer :(